# appending the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container in typeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I have to append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container for that I have created a  c DIV element that will contain the items (values)

I tried it with the code given below but this is more like javaScript , so I don't know implementing  DOM IN TypeScript kindly help into this

```
a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");


this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Renderer2` : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykhgsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div #container></div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  constructor(
    private R: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appendElement();
  }

  appendElement() {
    const el = this.R.createElement('a');
    this.R.setAttribute(el, 'id', 'autocomplete-list');
    this.R.setAttribute(el, 'class', 'autocomplete-items');
    const txt = this.R.createText('This is a link');
    this.R.appendChild(el, txt);

    this.R.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, el);
  }
}
```